# Unable to add text and link to new tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I scraped the following HTML to get link information, created a new tag, added the link to the new tag then attempted to append that tag to another document but lost all HTML formatting:

```
data = """
<div class="Answer">
1. BOUNDARIES - EPB &amp; APL&nbsp;<i>(inferior)</i>, EPL&nbsp;<i>(superior).&nbsp;</i><div>2. FLOOR (proximal to distal) - radial styloid =&gt; scaphoid =&gt; trapezium =&gt; 1st MC base.&nbsp;<br /><div>3. CONTENTS - cutaneous branches of radial nerve&nbsp;<i>(on the roof),</i>&nbsp;cephalic vein&nbsp;<i>(begins here),</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;radial artery&nbsp;<i>(on the floor).</i></div></div><div><br /></div><div><img src="paste-27a44c801f0776d91f5f6a16a963bff67f0e8ef3.jpg" /><br /></div><div><b>Image:&nbsp;</b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
image_link = soup.find('div').find('b').next.next
print(image_link)
```

I scraped the above data to get the following reference link (this is the format I require):

`Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/">Radiopaedia.org</a>. From the case <a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525">rID: 52525</a> [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].`

But adding the above reference link to a new tag loses all HTML formatting:

```
p_tag = soup.new_tag('p')
p_tag.append(soup.new_tag('br'))
p_tag.append(soup.new_tag('b'))
p_tag.b.append("Image: ")
p_tag.append(NavigableString(image_link))
print(p_tag)
```

Returns:

```
<p><br/><b>Image: </b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</p>
```

All HTML formatting is lost. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because type of `image_link` is `NavigableString` or string it will convert character like `<` to `&lt;` you need to convert it to `Tag` by creating new `soup`

```
....
p_tag.b.append("Image: ")
image_tag = BeautifulSoup(image_link, 'html.parser')
p_tag.append(image_tag)
```

or unescape the result

```
from html import unescape

....
p_tag.append(NavigableString(image_link))
unescaped_p = unescape(str(p_tag))
print(unescaped_p)
```

Comment: Dude! You da man! Dari Malaysia? I am a hobbyist and do a lot of work with BeautifulSoup and Scrapy, I’m thinking of making a Discord/Slack group. Would you be interested in joining?